# Undefined is not a function - SPServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

Console Log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.html:77
LoadCat index.html:77
(anonymous function) index.html:107
n.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
r.handle
```

Code:

```
        function LoadCat(cat) {

        if (cat != null) {

        var CAML = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Department" /><Value Type="Text">' + cat + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>';

        }
        else {

        var CAML = '';
        }


    var liHtml = "Category:  <select name=\"categoryselect\" id=\"categoryselect\">";

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        webURL: "PSS/StaffShop/",
        listName: "Categories",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: CAML,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                liHtml = liHtml + "<option value=\"" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "\" >" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</option>";


            });
            liHtml = liHtml + "</select>";
            $("#cat").html(liHtml);
        }

    });
    }
```

Code call:

```
$('.area').click(function(){ 

alert($(this).attr("href")); 

LoadCat();

});
```

The code is failing on this line:

```
   $().SPServices({
```

However

```
- JQuery is loaded
- SPServices is loaded
- Function is called in document ready
```

Full code is here for those interested: http://pastebin.com/NvSCjV72

EDIT:

It seems that SPServices reference is being lost on click?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 3):

Jquery was defined twice which was causing SPServices not to load correctly.